# Symfony Terminal fos elastic populate

Tags: php, symfony, foselasticabundle

I need run command in service

```
app/console fos:elastica:populate --no-reset --index=profile --type=team
```

by terminal all work fine but I need run in service

```
 $application = new \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application($this->kernel);
        $application->setAutoExit(false);
        //Upload in Elastic
        $options = array('command' => 'fos:elastica:populate', "--no-reset" => true, "--index=profile" => true, "--type=team" => true);
        $upload = $application->run(new \Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput($options));
```

have error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                    
The "--index=profile" option does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to use `Process` Component to launch the specific command:

```
// .../Service/YourService.php

use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

class YourService
{
    /.../

    public function launchPopulateCommand()
    {
        $process = new Process('php app/console fos:elastica:populate --no-reset --index=profile --type=team');
        $process->run();
    }

    /.../
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved

```
        $options = array('command' => 'fos:elastica:populate', "--no-reset" => true, "--index" => 'profile', "--type" => 'team');
        $upload = $application->run(new \Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput($options));
```